# how to get reverse(not complement or inverse) of a binary number

Tags: matlab

I am implementing cooley-tuckey `fft(raddix - 2 DIF / DIT)` algorithm in matlab.In that for the bit reversing i want to have reverse of an binary number. so can anyone suggest how can I get the reverse of a `binary number(like 100111 -> 111001)`. One who have worked on fft implementation can help me with the algorithm also.

Comment: How do you have that number defined? A vector of binary values? A decimal value?

Comment: Build a look-up table.  Do the whole `bin2dec(fliplr(dec2bin()))` thing for each number from 0 to 2^N, and store the results in an array `bitrev`.  Now you can just do `bitrev(x)`.  Plus it's already vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

[Topic: How to do bit reversal in Matlab?](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5393793) .

> If you're using double precision floating point ('double') numbers
>   which are integers, you can do this:
>
> dr = bin2dec(fliplr(dec2bin(d,n))); % Bits in dr are in reverse order
>
> where n is the number of bits to be reversed and where 0 <= d < 2^n.
>
> You will experience no precision problems at all as long as the
>   integers are no more than 52 bits long.

And

[Re: How to do bit reversal in Matlab?](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5393829)

> How large will the numbers be that you need to reverse? May I ask what
>   is the purpose of it? Maybe there is a more efficient way to solve the
>   whole problem. If the numbers are large you can just store the bits as
>   a string. To reverse it just read the string backwards! Or use
>   fliplr().

(There may be better places to ask).

If it were VHDL I'd suggest an alias with 'REVERSE'RANGE.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from the help section;

Y = swapbytes(X) reverses the byte ordering of each element in array X, converting little-endian values to big-endian (and vice versa). The input array must contain all full, noncomplex, numeric elements.

Comment: This swaps bytes, not bits

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. No wonder I wasn't getting the result I expected. I took 'reverse the byte ordering' as taking a byte and reversing it not taking bytes and reversing them.